# YouTube is really slow and changes the length of videos

Tags: youtube

For me YouTube has gotten worse and worse for the last past months. It buffers really slow (I have ~50 Mbit/s so I should be more than fine), errors that occurs (A 10 minute video can stop at 1:23 and think it's done).

Is there anything I can do to make this better? I'm using Google Chrome (27.0.1453.93) on OSX 10.8.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Try YouTube "Feather" Beta](http://www.youtube.com/feather_beta)

> This is an opt-in beta for "Feather" support on YouTube. The "Feather"
>   project is intended to serve YouTube video watch pages with the lowest
>   latency possible. It achieves this by severely limiting the features
>   available to the viewer and making use of advanced web techniques for
>   reducing the total amount of bytes downloaded by the browser. It is a
>   work in progress and may not work for all videos.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use to change the quality of the video like 240 p, 360 p, 480 p or 720 p. 
Or disabled some extensions on google chrome related to youtube or video.

Answer (score 0):

Try enabling the YouTube HTML5 Video Player [here](http://www.youtube.com/html5) for YouTube videos instead of using Chrome's built-in Adobe Flash Player.

Answer (score 0):

This is another option for to make it less laggy.
It's not exactly a fix but more of a workaround.

You take your video url for example:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3GJUM6pCpew

now add this.

https://www.youtube.com/embed/3GJUM6pCpew

You see you replace

**watch?v=**

with

**embed/**

**Now you will just have the video playing in your browser without any other part of the YouTube website. It makes the load a lot lighter on your browser.**

Answer (score -2):

This has happened for me a lot.

I found that clearing your cookies and cache fixes it.